# How to remove tag?

Tags: support, tags, editing

I accidentally created new tag while editing a question. I need to remove from this site. Is there any privileges required to do so? Or It will automatically get removed after I delete from the question (because that was only tag which is now removed)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, tags get automatically removed if there are no questions tagged with them. That's the only way normal users can remove a tag.

I wouldn't worry about it, just wait a while and it will disappear. Unused tags are purged automatically once a day.